# Modify data displaying on the default dialer app in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to insert additional data about incoming call on the default incoming call activity? I want to add data about incoming call that i get from my database. It should look like a incoming number and under number placed my data(name or organization).
I know, that it is possible to display another window above dialer while incoming call.
Maybe it is possible to do with content provider? Or is there another ways to do it?